# I keep getting a file not found error

Tags: java, input, output, average

Here's the prompt:

Write a program that reads a file containing two columns of floating-point numbers. Prompt the user for the file name. Print the average of each column.

My problem is that my program can't find my input file.

EDIT: I am no longer getting the "File not found." error but rather my program doesnt doi anything after the file is found...

Here's my code:

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter file name.");
    String file = in.next();
    try {
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(file));
        int count = 0;
        float average1 = 0;
        float average2 = 0;
        while (inFile.hasNextFloat()) {
            String str = inFile.nextLine();
            Scanner line = new Scanner(str);
            line.useDelimiter(" ");
            average1 = Float.parseFloat(line.next());
            average2 = Float.parseFloat(line.next());
            average1 += in.nextFloat();
            average2 += in.nextFloat();
        }
        System.out.println("The average of the first column: " + average1 / count);
        System.out.println("The average of the second column: " + average2 / count);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("File not found.");
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you giving full qualified file path in file name?

Comment: What happens if you pass the file name directly (i.e. hard-code it `file=""`).

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are giving a wrong path.
Are you typing the full path to the file? like "c:\documents\file.txt"? If you are using windows go to properties, open general tab and see the file's location.

Answer (score 0):

Place the file  in your project base directory

Also Do this

```
System.out.println(openFile.getAbsolutePath());
```

It will show you where JVM expects to find the file and whether it is the folder you expect as well, Accordingly place the file or give the exact location

If you do the above , you see that your file is in say C:\Harley\Test\strength.txt ie: it is expecting the file in the project base directory

*[you can also check if your file is in the same location as your .class file is. In the bin directory. Thereby you understand better]*

sample code snippet:

```
String file = "filename.txt";
 File openFile = new File(file);
        Scanner inFile = new Scanner(openFile);

        while (inFile.hasNext()) {
            line = inFile.nextLine();
            System.out.println(line);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the problem:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ExampleClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter file name.");

    // you put 'in.next();' put 'in.nextLine()'.
    String file = in.nextLine();
try {
    Scanner inFile = new Scanner(new File(file));
    int count = 0;
    float average1 = 0;
    float average2 = 0;
    while (inFile.hasNextFloat()) {
        String str = inFile.nextLine();
        Scanner line = new Scanner(str);
        line.useDelimiter(" ");
        average1 = Float.parseFloat(line.next());
        average2 = Float.parseFloat(line.next());
        average1 += in.nextFloat();
        average2 += in.nextFloat();
    }
    System.out.println("The average of the first column: " + average1 / count);
    System.out.println("The average of the second column: " + average2 / count);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    System.out.println("File not found.");
}
}

}
```

If it is still not working are you entering the path using '\' ? if you are then you have to enter the path like '/' example:

```
C:\Users\
```

Would produce an error.

```
C:/Users/
```

Would not.

Comment: It is not good practice to give the entire path in the program. Also 'in.next(); will still read the file text, it won't give FileNotFoundException. but good suggestion.

Comment: Okay, I changed it but now it isn't doing anything.... After I enter the file name the program just runs without anything happening.

Comment: I'm not sure, what I'm trying to say is that it never prints out the averages.

Comment: What do you mean? and here's the input file, 3.45 5.65
100.1 300.4
.54 65.0
20 30
546.75 90.87
123 456
987.654 123.456 each pair of numbers is on a line

Comment: It's because you are calling the `in` scanner in your loop. I don't think you meant to. In fact you should have closed it once you read the filename. See my answer below.